# Not able to open login page with routerLink

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I am trying to navigate to /login page whenever user clicks on the Login/Signup option present in my header component. But, whenever I clicks on Login/signUp it remains on the same page.

My app-routing.module.ts file is as below

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {LoginComponent} from './modules/login/login.component';
import {BlogComponent} from './modules/blog/blog.component';

const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'blog',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'blog',
    component: BlogComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '**',
        component: BlogComponent
      }
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {LoginComponent} from './modules/login/login.component';
import {BlogComponent} from './modules/blog/blog.component';

const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'blog',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'blog',
    component: BlogComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '**',
        component: BlogComponent
      }
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

and the HTML tag from which I am trying to call this is placed in my header.component.html

```
<a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Sign In/Sign Up" routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active" class="login">Login/SignUp</a>
```

Also I have added router-outlet in my app.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Though when I manually navigates to the login page i.e. by entering **localhost:4200/login** in browser, it successfully opens the login page.

My complete code can be found here -

> https://github.com/vibhorgoyal18/atest-blog/tree/master/src/app

Comment: But just is not working '/login' or all they are not working?

Comment: /blog is the default route. So, that works fine. Also I am able to load components successfully into my blog components. But /login is not working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, I was really humble with you. I mean, I clone your project because the problem was really rare. I just gonna tell you this. For the next occasions, try firts to review all your code and then present the problem here on the community.

The problem was that you've in your project a `ContentComponent` and inside it you're calling some services but you want to `unsubscribe` that services on the ngOnDestroy event cycle.

```
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  pageContent: string;
  blogContentSubscription: Subscription;
  contentSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private blogService: BlogService, private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.blogContentSubscription = this.blogService.selectedNode.subscribe((node) => {
      this.blogService.getPageContent(node).subscribe(data => {
      }, (res: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.pageContent = res.error.text;
      });
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.blogContentSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.contentSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

If you look the code, you're calling `blogContentSubscription` and then unsubscribe but you also unsubscribe `contentSubscription` but you're not calling before. So, the result is...

`Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined`

and that is what it's stopping the login route. You just need to remove the line where you unsubscribe the `contenSubscription` and it's going to work.

Try to review it better next time. It would be impossible if you don't post all the details

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the RoutingModule to the module that declares the HeaderComponent

Comment: I tried importing RouterModule in my app.component.ts and header.component.ts both. But none helped.